# PHP: Как в библиотеке PHPWORD решить проблему русской кодировки в 2020 году?

Tags: php, xml, кодировка, ms-word, phpword

коллеги!

Паршу XML-выдачу Яндекс и загоняю результаты в файл docx Word. Делаю это при помощи библиотеки PHPWORD таким манером:

```
$section->addText($result);
       $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

В получившийся файл helloWorld.docx что-то записывается, но Word не хочет его открывать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я пытаюсь открыть файл блокнотом, то текст показывается, но в виде краказябров

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузер все данные выводятся нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я подозреваю, что проблема в кодировке, но что отредактировать в библиотеке PHPWORD - не понимаю.. Советы все в интернете старые по времени (вот, например: http://phpword.blogspot.com/2012/03/russkiy-yasik-v-phpword.html), у меня даже нет тех файлов, так как библиотеку только установил.. Может быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался со схожей проблемой недавно? Буду благодарен за любой совет и помощь...

P.S. Если развернуть детали в сообщении, которое показывается при открытии файла в Word, то там написано xml parsing error

Comment: 'Если я пытаюсь открыть файл блокнотом, то текст показывается, но в виде краказябров': docx - zip-архив, его нужно разархивировать сначала

Comment: Попробовал вот такой пример из доков разработчиков PHPWORD. Вместо своей переменной вставил их текст: $section = $phpWord->addSection();
// Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...
$section->addText(
    '"Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. '
        . 'The important thing is not to stop questioning." '
        . '(Albert Einstein)'
);

Comment: Текст записался и открылся в Word нормально..

Comment: Получается, не в архиве дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге удалось получить XML в отчет Word! Архивация и кодировки оказались ни при чем.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выяснилось, что Word не воспринимает некоторые спецсимволы XML-льки, в частности: & и <, поэтому Word при открытии выдает ошибку Parsing XML error. Чтобы решить проблему, нужно добавить до всех манипуляций с Word подключение специального метода PHPWORD:
`PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);` Он предназначен для обработки нерасшифрованных символов xml.
Вот тут некоторые альтернативные решения (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301312/xml-parsing-error-phpword), но в моем случае сработал упомянутый.